# Fuzzy Inference system in R

Tags: machine-learning, r, fuzzy-logic

I want to use R for implementing a fuzzy inference system. There are 4 input variables and one output. Each rule is dependent on all input variables and based on there membership the output class is decided.

Can anyone suggest a good library and source examples to begin with? The library that have good visualisation support also.
Should I go with 'frbs' R package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "frbs", "sets" and fugeR packege for fuzzy logic model building.